# OOP - where to declare properties?

Tags: php, oop

My parent class has a few methods that rely on properties that can only be set by the child classes. What's the "best" approach to achieve this?

1. Parent class has the properties set to defaults (e.g. a string is set to null string), then child class sets parent's properties in its constructor.
2. The child class defines the properties as its own
3. Should the parent class' methods accept the necessary values as parameters, instead?
4. Something else???

Also - is it bad OOP that the parent methods rely on something that the child needs to provide?

I'm doing this in PHP, if that matters.

Comment: Yes it is bad design and not OOP when the parent relies upon something only the child can provide. Properties and methods flow from the parent to the child.

Comment: Should the parent methods accept the necessary values as parameters, then?

Comment: Sounds like you want both an interface and a base class, separately, that the children can implement

Comment: Why not pass these values to the base class' constructor?

Comment: @JoePhillips The implementations are exactly the same between all children classes. Imagine a method that, says, outputs the name of the child (e.g. "Hello Joe"). The "Joe" part is unknown to the base class; only the child class has that information.

Comment: @Quentin from child class' constructor to base class' constructor to base class' properties?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie yes. That'd avoid the weird "default" placeholder values.

Comment: @Quentin - you would still need to have defaults

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie is that a limitation of PHP? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: *"I'm doing this in PHP, if that matters."* -- it matters a lot, as the OOP languages are not born equal. Tag the question with [tag:php] and put some code in it, to better express it.

Comment: *"My parent class has a few methods that rely on properties that can only be set by the child classes."* -- Does the parent class model an abstract concept? If no, then this is just bad design.

Comment: @scrappedcola Why is this bad OOP design? If it was bad OOP design they never would have invented the abstract keyword or even the interface.

Comment: @Blackbam abstract is for defining things you want your child to inherit and define themselves. It's a form of contract. All objects have this but they each define what it means for themselves. What the op is describing is not downward inheritance but having a parent class depend (ie use) a value that the child sets. That is not what abstract does.

Comment: I don't think the question paints a clear picture of the problem. Why does a subclass needs to set them? How are these objects being used?

Answer (score 8):

So... You have one class that has an algorithm and another class that is responsible to provide the data for that algorithm... When I word it this way, does it still make sense to you for one of these classes to be a parent of the other?

Your "parent class" should take an object of the "child class" probably as a parameter in a constructor and then use that object to do its work. This *compositional pattern* is far more reliable, reusable and understandable.

See the Strategy Pattern in the design patterns literature for more information.

---

In other words, instead of this:

```
+--------------+
|    Parent    |
+--------------+
|*getName()    |
|showGreeting()|
+-----+--------+
      ^
      |
      |
 +----+-----+
 |  Child   |
 +----------+
 |*getName()|
 +----------+
```

Do this:

```
+--------------------+    +----------+
|       Parent       |    |  Child   |
+--------------------+    +----------+
|Parent(child: Child)|--->| getName()|
|showGreeting()      |    +----------+
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Say the parent class has a method `showGreeting`, which just outputs "Hello, my name is `*first_name*`". Assume that `*first_name*` is something only the child class is aware of. What's the ideal way to pass that information from child to parent? As a param: `showGreeting($first_name)`? The problem is that there are a lot of these values I would need to pass - almost 10. And I would have to keep creating method signatures with so many params because this is a recurring issue for many of the methods.

Comment: Pass the child object to the parent when the latter is constructed.

Comment: That's almost like passing itself to itself. Is this typical? Good practice?

Comment: No it's not like passing itself to itself. The sub-class relationship shouldn't exist in this case. The so called `Child` class is just a data bucket, not a proper object. Yes, it's good practice.

Answer (score 4):

The way to handle this in PHP is the same way you handle it in any decent language -- with `protected abstract` methods.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

```
<?php
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    // Our abstract method only needs to define the required arguments
    abstract protected function prefixName($name);
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass
{

    // Our child class may define optional arguments not in the parent's  signature
    public function prefixName($name, $separator = ".") {
        if ($name == "Pacman") {
            $prefix = "Mr";
        } elseif ($name == "Pacwoman") {
            $prefix = "Mrs";
        } else {
            $prefix = "";
        }
        return "{$prefix}{$separator} {$name}";
    }
}

$class = new ConcreteClass;
echo $class->prefixName("Pacman"), "\n";
echo $class->prefixName("Pacwoman"), "\n";
?>
```

Comment: So your solution is to pass the necessary values as parameters of the method? There are a lot (about 10) that I would need to pass, then. That's too many parameters for a method.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I think, Bryan not only shows a way of forcing the subclasses to provide values (`return...`) needed in the parent class, but also the fact that the parent shouldn't work with child properties, but only with method implementations in the child classes. And I think you're making a little mistake: `$name` and maybe `$separator` are NOT the properties about which you are speaking in your original question, e.g the "_properties that can only be set by the child classes._". No, the returning values of the abstract method implements are the property values you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724694/oop-where-to-declare-properties#comment76656382_44769919), it sounds like you're talking about [subtyping polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping). The basic idea behind polymorphism is that you can do something like this.

**Option 1**: No default. This should be used if calling this function should never happen from the parent (e.g. Shape) class

```
class Shape
{
    // This doesn't make sense until we know what shape we're talking about
    abstract public function getArea();
}
```

Then you have children classes that look like this:

```
class Square extends Shape
{
    public $sideLength;

    public function getArea()
    {
        return ($this->sideLength ** 2);
    }
}

class Triangle extends Shape
{
    public $base;
    public $height;

    public function getArea()
    {
        return ($this->base * $this->height * 0.5);
    }
}

etc.
```

**Option 2**: If the function should be able to be called in the parent, you would include the properties and the function itself.

```
class Rectangle
{
    public $length;
    public $width;

    public function getArea()
    {
        return ($this->length * $this->width);
    }
}
```

Then you have children classes that look like this:

```
class Square extends Rectangle
{
    public $length;

    public function getArea()
    {
        return ($this->length ** 2);
    }
}
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is a very broad question and the answer entirely depends on the use case. Let me show by using some easy examples:

**Your first suggestion:**

```
abstract class Vehicle {
 String name = "SuperDriver";
 int numberOfWheels = 4;
 int maxSpeed = 20;

 public function drive(Terrain terrain) {
   echo this.name." drives with ".(this.maxSpeed - terrain->modifier)." mph in ".terrain->name;
 }

}

class Car extends Vehicle {

  public function __construct() {
    this.name="Ferrari";
    this.numberOfWheels = 4;
    this.maxSpeed = 310;
  }

}

class Bicycle extends Vehicle {
  public function __construct() {
    this.name="Mountain Bike";
    this.numberOfWheels = 2;
    this.maxSpeed = 150;
  }
}
```

**Advantages:**

You even could instantiate Vehicle if you do not declare it abstract and it could even drive.

**Disadvantages:**

- A non-concrete Vehicle does not make a lot of sense
- Anybody how extends the class has to know that all the properties must be overwritten
- hard to extend and hard to maintain
- maybe others ...

**Your second suggestion:**

```
abstract class Vehicle {

 public function drive(Terrain terrain) {
   echo this.name." drives with ".(this.maxSpeed - terrain->modifier)." mph in ".terrain->name;
 }

}

class Car extends Vehicle {

    this.name="Ferrari";
    this.numberOfWheels = 4;
    this.maxSpeed = 310;

}

class Bicycle extends Vehicle {

    this.name="Mountain Bike";
    this.numberOfWheels = 2;
    this.maxSpeed = 150;
}
```

I can not see any advantage. If the parent class needs those properties you should definitly make them required. If the parent class does not need any of those properties then this is child class territory which you should not care about.

**Your third suggestion:**

```
abstract class Vehicle {

 protected function drive(Terrain terrain, String name, int maxSpeed) {
   echo name." drives with ".(maxSpeed - terrain->modifier)." mph in ".terrain->name;
 }

 abstract public function drive(Terrain terrain);

}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    this.name="Ferrari";
    this.numberOfWheels = 4;
    this.maxSpeed = 310;

  function drive(Terrain terrain) {
   parent::drive(terrain,this.name,this.maxSpeed);
  }
}

class Bicycle extends Vehicle {
    this.name="Mountain Bike";
    this.numberOfWheels = 2;
    this.maxSpeed = 150;

  function drive(Terrain terrain) {
   parent::drive(terrain,this.name,this.maxSpeed);
  }
}
```

Advantages:

- You have some flexibility now
- You can extend the drive method

Disadvantages:

- Basically you declare two different methods with the same name in order to achieve what you want so this is a workaround
- not very flexible

**This is how you could force unchangeable properties:**

```
abstract class Vehicle {
 String name;
 int numberOfWheels;
 int maxSpeed;

 public function __construct() {

 }

 protected abstract function getName();
 protected abstract function getNumberOfWheels();
 protected abstract function getMaxSpeed();

 public function drive(Terrain terrain) {
   echo this.getName()." drives with ".(this.getMaxSpeed() - terrain->modifier)." mph in ".terrain->name;
 }

}

class Car extends Vehicle {

  protected function getName() { return "Ferrari"; }
  protected function getNumberOfWheels() { return 4; }
  protected function getMaxSpeed() { return 310; }

}

class Bicycle extends Vehicle {
  protected function getName() { return "Mountain Bike"; }
  protected function getNumberOfWheels() { return 2; }
  protected function getMaxSpeed() { return 150; }
}
```

If you do it this way nobody can change the properties from outside, only subclasses.

**You also could use a protected constructor in the superclass:**

```
abstract class Vehicle {
 String name;
 int numberOfWheels;
 int maxSpeed;

 protected function __construct($name,$numberOfWheels,$maxSpeed) {
   this.name = name;
   this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
   this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
 }

 public function drive(Terrain terrain) {
   echo this.name." drives with ".(this.maxSpeed - terrain->modifier)." mph in ".terrain->name;
 }

}

class Car extends Vehicle {
   // or pass the arguments here, if you want an outside user to set em    
   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct("Ferrari",4,310);
   }

}
```

Why this works:

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to
>   parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the
>   child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the
>   parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared
>   as private).

If you have public properties which just should be initialized simply use constructor arguments.

**Your second question:** *Is it bad OOP that the parent methods rely on something that the child needs to provide?*

In my opinion no, not necessarily. Otherwise there would be only interfaces and no *abstract classes* or e.g. *Traits (PHP)*. Mechanisms like this **avoid duplicate code**.

Comment: I'm digesting your solution. In your **This is how you could force unchangeable properties:** section, you defined a bunch of methods ("getters") in place of the properties. I _feel_ that the properties should remain as properties -- not converted into methods. I do see the benefit of this approach as the child classes would need to implement those methods. Your **You also could use a protected constructor in the superclass:** section seems more correct, except I have about 20 of these properties -- and 20 parameters seem excessive.

Comment: If you have that many parameters - no matter which approach you choose - you may want to define a seperate property class and pass this as a single parameter or use this as a single getter? class VehicleProperties in my example do you know what I mean?